# Using definite article before abbreviations

Tags: definite-article, abbreviations

Consider this part of a technical article.

> Approaches to boilerplate detection typically exploit **DOM-
>   level features** of segments by means of handcrafted rules or trained classifiers, or they identify common, i.e., frequently used segments or patterns/shingles on a website ..... Yi et al. simplify **the DOM structure** by deriving a so-called Site Style Tree which is then used for classification [26]. Baluja [2] employs decision tree learning and entropy reduction for template detection at **DOM level**.

DOM is abbreviation for Document Object Model, in this article sometimes it is used with "the" and sometimes without it, Why? As I checked another document, they may use **the DOM tree** but **DOM trees**.

I guess as the DOM tree and the DOM structure is unique, they use "the"

In general, are there rules for definite article and abbreviations?

Answer (score 1):

In general treat the abbreviation as if it were expanded, and act accordingly.

It is not because the DOM tree is *unique* that the definite article is used, but because it is a specific tree, the tree of the Document Object Model.

In `DOM trees` the plural refers to the noun *generically/collectively*.

The Asian elephant has smaller ears than the African elephant.

*Asian elephants* have smaller ears than African elephants.

*Chrysler engines* are often a little larger|smaller than those of their competitors.

Comment: I always was doubtful where *the* may be used before a N + N construction, once I thought even A + N get articles like *the red color*, but they said no it could be "red color". Here DOM seems like an attribute or it is a specific N+N construction which needs *the*?!

Comment: The acronym is used attributively. The DOM tree.

Comment: So the DOM tree but not the red color? Why?

Comment: Try searching for article with color here. I know the subject has come up many times. Also, CONTEXT IS EVERYTHING. You must use phrases in full sentences.

Comment: I found some, but my question actually is if we use an adjective for a countable object so it makes it specific, then we use "the"? "the red color" or "red', means "the color that is red among colors". For example "the green continent" to mean the only continent which is green?

Comment: Ask this question separately. As I said, no fragments ("the green continent") only full sentences in your examples.

Comment: I asked it in this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64067/can-adjectives-make-a-noun-definite